# Jquery or Javascript text rotator inside DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have a DIV with ready and nice looking CSS text and inside this div I need to show some simple notes short notes without links without images.

Example:

```
<div class="box-textholder">
text one: here we show text one for 5 secs
text two: here we show text twofor 5 secs
text three: here we show text three for 5 secs
</div>
```

After this we show text one again and so on

I tried a lot of jquery news tickers and code I found here but I cannot find or make any one to work in a very short simple way. Almost all ready made scripts are complicated because they are made for other kind of functions. What I need is very simple. Here is the shortest and simplest code I found but is not working... Any ideas?

```
<script>
        $(function(){
            $('box-textholder').billboard({messages : [


                'text one is here',
                'text two is here',
                'text three is here', 
                'text four is here'
            ]});
        });
</script>
```

Is there any simple way to do this? I already have Jquery

Here is the plugin billboard

```
(function(e,t,n){"use strict";e.billboard=function(t,n){var r={messages:[],interval:5e3},i=this,s=0,o=e(t);i.settings={};var u=function(){clearTimeout(i.timerId);if(s>=i.settings.messages.length-1){s=0}else{s++}e(t).fadeOut("slow",function(){e(t).text(i.settings.messages[s])});e(t).fadeIn("slow");i.timerId=setTimeout(u,i.settings.interval)};var a=function(){o.stop().removeAttr("style");clearTimeout(i.timerId)};var f=function(){i.timerId=setTimeout(u,i.settings.interval)};i.init=function(){i.settings=e.extend({},r,n);o.on("click",function(){u()});o.hover(a,f);f()};i.init()};e.fn.billboard=function(t){return this.each(function(){if(n==e(this).data("billboard")){var r=new e.billboard(this,t);e(this).data("billboard",r)}})}})(jQuery,window)
```

Comment: This appears to need a plugin called billboard - are you including that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to use isn't jQuery only, `billboard` is a plugin to jQuery you need to include to your project in order to use it. You can find some documentation and downloads [here](http://www.jqueryscript.net/slideshow/Easy-jQuery-Responsive-Slideshow-Plugin-Billboard.html).

That being said, I wouldn't use it for your use case as some simple javascript will do what you want.

```js
var textArray = ['text1','text2','text3'],
    i = 0;
    setInterval(function(){
         i = i == textArray.length ? 0 : i;
         document.getElementById('box').innerHTML = textArray[i];
         i = i + 1;
    },5000);
```

```html
<div id="box">text1</div>
```

Now simply give your text box an id according to above selector ( in this case box ) and put the code in a script tag after the html. You can add or change the text in the textArray array.

Answer (score 0):

The plugin you're trying to use is [Billboard by Brian Muenzenmeyer](https://github.com/bmuenzenmeyer/billboard). It is also [listed](https://plugins.jquery.com/billboard/) on the jQuery plugin's page. Just make sure you download and link to the `billboard-0.1.1.min.js` file listed on their GitHub and it should work just fine.